# Should I check my underwear each time before prayer?

Tags: salat, taharah, najis

Sometimes I find impurities on my underwear. So should I check for impurities each time before salah? I also have feeling sometimes of impurity but don't know if it's a waswasah or not.

Comment: What is the type of impure substance you find, i.e urine, menstrual blood?

Comment: When do you find those impurities, i.e is it after you pass urine or gass?

Comment: Yes you should check your Underwear for impurities, If the imourities are not there but only limited to your imagination. Please consider visiting a Psychiatrist

Comment: It's semen.....

Comment: Semen is ok - allah made you to perfection and semen is part of that perfection. Just to be sure, I'd suggest to check other people's underwear too.

Answer (score -1):

One of the requirements for prayer is Purity. Impurities can be visible and invisible. Stool, urine, menstrual blood are all considered impurities thus must be removed before praying, either by a change of clothing or washing the clothes. There are some dispensations available i.e. hardship.

Comment: This is good advice and fact, but not an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: its implied? ofcourse it answer it

Answer (score -2):

You should check your underwear and any other clothes you are wearing, before prayer, if you are even the simplest bit **unsure**. It is always best to be safe. If you are, however, **absolutely sure** that there are no impure substances in your clothing, there is no need to check.

Comment: Are you able to [back this up](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) with references?  Otherwise the answer is just the opinion of some random person on the Internet.